# priority queue error

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am having trouble, Whenever I try to compile this program I get an error in the contains function where it says q.pop. If that line is commented out it will compile fine, but it stills gives the wrong value. It is always false for some reason.

The error is:
`priority_queue_demo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
priority_queue_demo.cpp:54:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/bits/basic_string.tcc:214:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
priority_queue_demo.cpp: In function 'bool contains(const std::priority_queue<T>&, T) [with T = int, typename std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >::value_type = int]':
priority_queue_demo.cpp:43:47:   instantiated from here
priority_queue_demo.cpp:27:3: error: passing 'const std::priority_queue<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::pop() [with _Tp = int, _Sequence = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, _Compare = std::less<int>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <queue>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, priority_queue<T> &q) {
        os << "{";
        while (!q.empty()) {
               os << q.top() << (!q.empty() ? ", " : "");
               q.pop();
        }

        os << "}";

        return os;
}

template <typename T>
bool contains(const priority_queue<T> &q, T val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) {
                if (q.top() == val) return true;
                q.pop();
        }

        return false;
}

int main() {
        cout << boolalpha;

        priority_queue<int> qi;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                qi.push(i);

        cout << qi << endl;

        cout << "qi contians 15: " << contains(qi, 15) << endl;
        cout << "qi contians 23: " << contains(qi, 23) << endl;

        const int ARR_SIZE = 4;
        string arr[ARR_SIZE] = {"cat", "dog", "cow", "elephant"};

        cout << endl;

        priority_queue<string> qs;

        for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
                qs.push(i);

        cout << qs << endl;

        while(!qs.empty()) {
                qs.pop();
                cout << qs << endl;
        }


        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What's the compiler error message?

Comment: There are other problems with your code. For instance, `qs` is a `priority_queue<string>` but you are pushing `int`s to it (in the line `qs.push(i)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a `const` reference to the queue, but `pop()` is obviously not a `const` operation, because it mutates the queue.

You should pass a non-const reference:

```
bool contains(priority_queue<T>& q, T val) { .... }
```

As you can see, you can't really check the contents of a queue without altering it.

The next error is that you are pushing an integer into a queue of `std::string`:

```
qi.push(i);
```

You probably mean

```
qi.push(arr[i]);
```

**Note** your overload of `ostream& operator<<` for the queue empties the queue, so any attempt to use `contains` after printing the queue to `std::cout` will yield false regardless of the original content of the queue.

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/Cgfz6e).

Comment: Another error is `qs.push(i);` where `i` is an `int` and `qs` is `priority_queue<string>`.

Comment: ok that works fine, but now it give me an error in the main, at line where it says priority_queue<string> qs;

Comment: @FJam that would be because you are pushing ints into it. See edit.

Comment: Yes, the function should take a non-const reference. And it's name should be changed to `tear_apart_queue_looking_for_element`.

Comment: ok thanks i got that to work, but the contains function is still giving me the wrong answer. it says false for both values.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in the code:

```
priority_queue<string> qs;

    for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
            qs.push(i);  //<<<<Error, should be arr[i]
```

You really should push `arr[i]` not `i` since `i` is integer while it expects `string.`

You pass the `priority_queue` by reference to the overloaded `<<` operator function,which removes all the elements in the `priority_queue`, so all your `contains` query will becomes `false`.

You also use `const priority_queue<T>&` in `contains` function, however, the `pop()` function is not `const`, which results in compile error as pointed out by juanchopanza.

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment before but there are other problems with your code that don't fit in  comments.

**1)** `qs` is a `priority_queue<string>` but you are pushing `int`s to it (in the line `qs.push(i)`); I guess what you wanted to do was to push `arr[i]`. Hence, replace

```
qs.push(i);
```

with

```
qs.push(arr[i]);
```

**2)** The template function `contains` take a `priority_queue<T>` by const reference. That means you can't call non `const` methods on `q`. In particular, you cannot call `q.pop()` because `pop()` is a non const method. (Indeed, this method is expected to change the queue.) Therefore, replace

```
template <typename T>
bool contains(const priority_queue<T> &q, T val) {
```

with

```
template <typename T>
bool contains(priority_queue<T> &q, T val) {
```